# Implement search field when data is dynamic with mysql database and php

Tags: android, xml

I am Developing an app in which i use a search view to show data which i want to search but i am unable to do this . i am new to android.how to search data when data is coming from server with mysql and php

```
package selva.select;

public class Worker extends Activity implements {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        setContentView(R.layout.worker);
        SearchView search;
        RelativeLayout rl;
        Button logout;

        logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent it = new Intent(Worker.this,Login.class);
                startActivity(it);
                    finish();
            }
        });

        ZoomControls zoom;
        final TableLayout tl;
        zoom = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls1);
        tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);

        zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                float x = tl.getScaleX();
                float y = tl.getScaleY();

                tl.setScaleX((float) (x+1));
                tl.setScaleY((float) (y+1));
            }
        });         

        zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  

                float x = tl.getScaleX();
                float y = tl.getScaleY();

                tl.setScaleX((float) (x-1));
                tl.setScaleY((float) (y-1));
            }
        });

        SearchView sv;

        sv= (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
        sv.setQueryHint("Search Worker Id");        

        String response = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://hcm4zealit.com/PHP/worker2.php");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Input Reading pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            is.close();

            response = sb.toString();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // parse json data
        try {   
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray jArray =  jObject.getJSONArray("result");

            TableLayout tv = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
            tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();

            int flag =1;

            for (int i = -1; i <= jArray.length()-1; i++) {
                //JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(Worker.this);
                tr.setClickable(true);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                if(flag==1) {

                    TextView b = new TextView(Worker.this);
                    b.setText(" Id");
                    b.setTextSize(17);
                    b.setTypeface(b.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
                    b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tr.addView(b);

                    TextView b1 = new TextView(Worker.this);
                    b1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    b1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                    b1.setTextSize(17);
                    b1.setTypeface(b1.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
                    b1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    b1.setText("Name");
                    tr.addView(b1);

                    TextView b2 = new TextView(Worker.this);
                    b2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    b2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                    b2.setTextSize(17);
                    b2.setTypeface(b2.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
                    b2.setText("Nationality");
                    tr.addView(b2);

                    TextView b3 = new TextView(Worker.this);
                    b3.setTextSize(17);
                    b3.setText("Company");
                    b3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    b3.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                    b3.setTypeface(b3.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
                    tr.addView(b3);
                    tv.addView(tr);
                    final View vline = new View(Worker.this);
                    vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
                    vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv.addView(vline);
                    flag = 0;

                } else {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    TextView b6 = new TextView(Worker.this);
                    // b6.setText("Worker Id");
                    b6.setText(json_data.getString("Worker_id"));
                    b6.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    b6.setTextSize(17);
                    tr.addView(b6);

                    TextView b19 = new TextView(Worker.this);
                    b19.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                    b19.setTextSize(17);
                    // b19.setText("Worker Name");
                    b19.setText(json_data.getString("Worker_name"));
                    b19.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tr.addView(b19);

                    TextView b29 = new TextView(Worker.this);
                    b29.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                    // b29.setText("Nationality");
                    b29.setText(json_data.getString("Nationality"));
                    b29.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    b29.setTextSize(17);
                    tr.addView(b29);

                    TextView b30 = new TextView(Worker.this);
                    b30.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                    // b30.setText("Company Name");
                    b30.setText(json_data.getString("company_name"));
                    b30.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    b30.setTextSize(17);
                    tr.addView(b30);
                    tv.addView(tr);

                    // set TableRow onClickListner

                    final View vline1 = new View(Worker.this);
                    vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                    vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv.addView(vline1);         
                }
            }
        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }           

        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);        

         Intent intent = getIntent();
         if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
              String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
              doMySearch(query);
         }      
    }

    private void doMySearch(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    //  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        //searchView.setOnQueryTextListener((OnQueryTextListener) this);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="#3498DB"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#34495E"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120sp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"                       
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view_rounde_corner"
        android:text="Logout" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="Search id"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view_rounde_corner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    </SearchView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Worker Report"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#F4F6F7"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ZoomControls
         android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:gravity="right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am Unable to add search field which can search data from a table . i am new in android..